# AWK to compare 2 csv files

Tags: csv, unix, awk, diff

Need help to compare 2 csv files. Number of columns are unknown.

File1

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

File2

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,2,3,4,5,5,7
7,6,6,4,3,2,1
```

Desired Output

```
Item  FILE1   FILE2
1     F=6     F=5
7     C=5     C=6
```

If there are more columns mismatch then output should like this.

```
Item  FILE1   FILE2
1     F=6     F=5
      ---     ---
      ---     ---
7     C=5     C=6
```

Comment: What did you try ? Show some effort before asking, or should I say almost ordering for an answer...

Comment: are the number of columns and column names the same in both files?

Comment: Yes, columns in both files are same and column count also same.

Comment: I tried sdiff -s -w 2000 file1 file2 > file3

Comment: does my answer solve your issue? ;-)

Comment: yes @Allan, it solved my issue

Comment: If you know what the Answer is, please post it. Otherwise this question does not help any future visitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
paste -d '\n' file1 file2 | sed '1d' | awk -F',' 'NR==1{print "Item\tFILE1\tFILE2";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)header[i]=$i;}NR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)l1[i]=$i;getline;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)l2[i]=$i;p=1;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(l1[i]!=l2[i])if(p){print l1[1]"\t"header[i]"="l1[i]"\t"header[i]"="l2[i];p=0;}else print " \t---\t---"}}'
```

**file1:**

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,2,3,1,4,6,7
7,6,5,2,3,2,1
```

**file2:**

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,2,3,4,5,5,7
7,6,6,4,3,2,1
```

**Explanations:**

- `paste -d '\n' file1 file2` will interleave the 2 input files

**output: (for my 2 input files)**

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,2,3,1,4,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,5,7
7,6,5,2,3,2,1
7,6,6,4,3,2,1
```

- `sed '1d'` delete the double header
- `awk` will save the header line in `header` array then; then fetch 2 lines per 2 and go through all the fields and save them in 2 arrays `l1` and `l2`, then we compare elements of those 2 arrays 1 by 1 and as soon as we have the first difference we print it, if we have already print a difference then `p` becomes `0` and we change  the output we print for new difference encountered

**final output: (for my 2 input files)**

```
Item    FILE1   FILE2
1       D=1     D=4
        ---     ---
        ---     ---
7       C=5     C=6
        ---     ---
```

**awk code formatted with -F',':**

```
NR==1{
    print "Item\tFILE1\tFILE2";
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)header[i]=$i;
}
NR>1{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)l1[i]=$i;
    getline;
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)l2[i]=$i;
    p=1;
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if(l1[i]!=l2[i])
          if(p){
            print l1[1]"\t"header[i]"="l1[i]"\t"header[i]"="l2[i];
            p=0;
          }
          else 
            print " \t---\t---"
    }
}
```

if you want to show all the differences use

```
NR==1{
    print "Item\tFILE1\tFILE2";
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)header[i]=$i;
}
NR>1{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)l1[i]=$i;
    getline;
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)l2[i]=$i;
    p=1;
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if(l1[i]!=l2[i])
          if(p){
            print l1[1]"\t"header[i]"="l1[i]"\t"header[i]"="l2[i];
            p=0;
          }
          else 
            print " \t"header[i]"="l1[i]"\t"header[i]"="l2[i];
    }
}
```

or in one command:

```
paste -d '\n' file1 file2 | sed '1d' | awk -F',' 'NR==1{print "Item\tFILE1\tFILE2";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)header[i]=$i;}NR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)l1[i]=$i;getline;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)l2[i]=$i;p=1;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(l1[i]!=l2[i])if(p){print l1[1]"\t"header[i]"="l1[i]"\t"header[i]"="l2[i];p=0;}else print " \t"header[i]"="l1[i]"\t"header[i]"="l2[i]; }}'
```

this produce the following output:

```
Item    FILE1   FILE2
1       D=1     D=4
        E=4     E=5
        F=6     F=5
7       C=5     C=6
        D=2     D=4
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick one but its not working if there are more than 1 difference, its showing only 1 and also for first occurrence diff.

Comment: do you want to print all differences??? Ok I can fix it for you I thought you didn't need it lol

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly could you try the last command at the bottom?

Comment: @Allan, I believe you can get rid of the paste if your change your `getline` in awk into `getline < "file2"` or put `file2` as a variable.

Comment: thanks for the tip! :) I will try to use it and edit it tomorrow time to take a rest :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Allan, This one gave whatever i was looking for. Much appreciate.

Comment: @Anand: If you liked my answer or if it solved your issue you can vote up, or accept it as anwer!  to give me some fame ;) ;) that's the principle of SO on top of helping people learning a lot and having fun!!! :)

Comment: @Allan is it possible to compare those lines only which are common in both files based on first column and exclude the uncommon rows to separate file.

Answer (score 2):

```
~> ( nl file1.txt && nl file2.txt ) | sort | awk 'BEGIN{cnt=1;print "Item\tFILE1\tFILE2"}{if (NR==1) split($2,col,",");}{if ((NR%2)==1){split($2,data_2_NR,",");}else {split($2,data_1_NR,",");  for (i in data_1_NR) if (data_1_NR[i]!=data_2_NR[i]) print cnt++ "-" data_1_NR[1] "\t"col[i]"="data_1_NR[i] "\t"col[i]"=" data_2_NR[i]  }}' }}'
```

## output:

```
Item    FILE1   FILE2
1-1     F=6     F=5
2-7     C=6     C=5
```

## explanation:

added line number to each file and sort result

```
( nl file1.txt && nl file2.txt ) | sort | \
```

output:

```
   1    A,B,C,D,E,F,G
   1    A,B,C,D,E,F,G
   2    1,2,3,4,5,5,7
   2    1,2,3,4,5,6,7
   3    7,6,5,4,3,2,1
   3    7,6,6,4,3,2,1
```

started counter (cnt) for number of diffs & print table titles

```
 awk 'BEGIN{cnt=1;print "Item\tFILE1\tFILE2"}\
```

get from first line the columns names (split $2 because we need the original content and not the numbering ,numbering was used for sorting )

```
 {if (NR==1) split($2,col,",");}\
```

due to the initial sort we have done we can look at odd and even lines for diffs
splitting odd lines to an array called data_2_NR

```
 {if ((NR%2)==1){split($2,data_2_NR,",");}\
```

even lines to an array called data_1_NR

```
 else {split($2,data_1_NR,",");\
```

run on all columns in data_1_NR & data_2_NR arrays and compare each array cell

```
 for (i in data_1_NR) if (data_1_NR[i]!=data_2_NR[i])\
```

if they are different print line in table

```
 print cnt++ "-" data_1_NR[1] "\t"col[i]"="data_1_NR[i] "\t"col[i]"=" data_2_NR[i]}}' }}'
```

## output

```
Item    FILE1   FILE2
1-1     F=6     F=5
2-7     C=6     C=5
```

Comment: 1) first added line numbers to each file , 2) sort t get the same line number together, 3) split first line to col array, 4)create 2 dim arrays (array for each file   5) if line is odd run on array and check for diff of col, 6) if different print to screen and update cnt

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain the code *in the anwer* instead.

Comment: Generally `awk '{if(foo) bar}'` is more idiomatically written `awk 'foo { bar }'` unless you specifically need an `else` branch (and sometimes even then).